# Include specific columns in Rails API/JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

This:

```
def index
    render json: Slide.all.to_json(include: :user)
end
```

Is rendering this:

```
[
    {
         id: 1,
         title: 'Hello',
         user: {
             first_name: 'Guilherme',
             last_name: 'Oderdenge',
             email: 'guilhermeoderdenge@gmail.com'
         }
    }
]
```

Ok. But I just want the `first_name` from `user`. There's a way to do this?

Comment: As a sidenote, if you need to customize a lot your json output, you should take a look at RABL https://github.com/nesquena/rabl

Comment: @Antoine good call, though I prefer https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
render json: Slide.all.to_json(include: { user: { only: :first_name} )
```

See [the rails api](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Change it like

```
render json: Slide.all.to_json(:include=>{:user=>{:only=>[:first_name]}})
```